# @output which was not supplied in sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

C# code:

```
protected void btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = Connection.DBconnection();   

    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("sp_studentresult", con);
    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", textstudentid.Text);

    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adp.Fill(ds);

    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {                   
        txtid.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["id"].ToString();
        txttamil.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Tamil"].ToString();
        txtenglish.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["English"].ToString();
        txtmaths.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Maths"].ToString();
        txtscience.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Science"].ToString();
        txtsocialscience.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SocialScience"].ToString();                     
    }

    SqlParameter retval = new SqlParameter("@output", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    retval.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    com.Parameters.Add(retval);

    com.ExecuteNonQuery();

    string Output = retval.Value.ToString();   
}
```

Stored procedure:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE sp_studentresult
(
    @id int,
    @output varchar(50) output,
    @id_student varchar(50)
)
AS
begin
SELECT * from studentresult where id_student=@id
End
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM student WHERE id=@id_student)
BEGIN
SET @output='EXIST'
END
```

I'm new to .net. When I enter student id and search I get

> Procedure or function sp_studentresult has too many arguments specified.

May I know what my mistake in the above code?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Show the store procedure code

Comment: Please post the stored procedure `sp_studentresult` here so we know what parameters this stored procedure takes.
By the way, have you checked the stored procedure is actually in the database?

Comment: can you please check my sp? thanks

Comment: Side note: [`CREATE PROCEDURE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187926.aspx): "Avoid the use of the **sp_** prefix when naming procedures. This prefix is used by SQL Server to designate system procedures. Using the prefix can cause application code to break..."

Comment: you have to post the code of sp_studentresult stored procedure

Answer (score 1):

i bet, you are trying to return a sql result set and an output parameter, right? if so, then try the code below:

```
protected void btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = Connection.DBconnection();

    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("sp_studentresult", con);
    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", textstudentid.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_student", textIDStudent.Text);
    SqlParameter retval2 = new SqlParameter("@output", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    retval2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    com.Parameters.Add(retval2);

    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adp.Fill(ds);

    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        txtid.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["id"].ToString();
        txttamil.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Tamil"].ToString();
        txtenglish.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["English"].ToString();
        txtmaths.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Maths"].ToString();
        txtscience.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Science"].ToString();
        txtsocialscience.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SocialScience"].ToString();
    }

    SqlParameter retval = new SqlParameter("@output", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    retval.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    com.Parameters.Add(retval);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", textstudentid.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_student", textIDStudent.Text);

    com.ExecuteNonQuery();

    string Output = retval.Value.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The stored procedure names are different.

```
  SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("sp_studentresult", con);
```

here you are referring to "sp_studentresult". The stored procedure code you have inserted is

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_searchupdate
```

Obviously the parameters list should be different for these procedures.

Comment: But the stored procedure code you have posted is sp_searchupdate. Post the code for sp_studentresult.

Comment: I couldn't comment on your post because of reputation <50. So i have posted this as an answer.

Comment: I posted sp_studentresult stored procedure.. but now it shows @output which was not supplied..

Answer (score 0):

Its because the stored procedure is not getting value for all the parameters , 
Check the number of parameters which are passed to the SP from SqlCommand .
If possible update your stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

You are missing parameter id_student which must supply.
Only the parameters marked as Output need not to supply.
Add it like you have added @id
e.g.
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Value);

I am not sure what will be the value for it , so you can put the correct value in place of variable Value

Comment: Output parameter need not to supply, but all other parameters you must supply.